# Missing class files after Maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, .class-file

I'm using Maven 3.3.9 on Windows 10. I have a multi-POM project, and I want to share some test resources across the Maven projects. As we all know the files in `src/test/*` won't be included in distribution JARs, so I created a separate project just for the test resources (and accompanying Java class with the resource names), so that I could share this project across other projects.

For the sake of illustration let's say that there are two files in the `foo-test` project:

- `src/main/java/com/example/foo/test/FooTestResources.java`
- `src/main/resources/com/example/foo/test/resource.txt`

Straightforward, right? Except that when I build the project in Maven, the resulting JAR file *only contains `com/example/foo/test/resource.txt`*! The class file, which I would expect to be in `com/example/foo/test/FooTestResources.class`, is missing.

In fact they this file isn't even in the `target` directory, so it's as if Maven isn't even compiling the source file. I searched my project directory for `FooTestResources.class`, and it doesn't exist. Only the source code file `FooTestResources.java` is there.

When I build the project on Eclipse 4.6.3, Eclipse generates the file `target/com/example/foo/test/FooTestResources.class` as expected. When I do a `mvn clean install` it disappears.

What is going on?

Comment: That is some weird stuff. Can you post your ``pom.xml``? Smells like some there's magic in there that's being ignored by the eclipse builder, hence the difference.

Comment: Without seeing the actual pom.xml my only guess is there is something in the pom that sets the source directory to something else. Add `-X` to your mvn command to see if it's actually compiling whatever under `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! Here's the story.

Once upon a time I had a project that needed two JARs. One JAR would contain the source code along with most of the resources, and the other would contain just a single resource. Rather than creating two projects (and two Git repositories), I tried to be lazy and I created two POMs. One POM built everything normally except for the one resource, the other… (you guessed it) ignored all the source files and generated the POM files.

You can read the full technical details here: https://globalmentor.atlassian.net/browse/CLOGR-3

For various reasons that didn't turn out to be the most manageable approach, so I split out the two POMs into separate projects repositories, as they should have been to begin with.

Unfortunately, somewhere along the way I copied the crucial lines from one of those POMs into this POM.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipMain>true</skipMain>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**The `skipMain` is what does it.** Bye-bye source files. (Apparently Eclipse ignores the details of this section.)

I was also skipping tests as well; I basically had just copied from the wrong POM, a POM I don't even have around anymore.